# Graphic rendering issue in Interface Builder VS simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

This first image is a screenshot from IB. It it I have spaced out two elements to better see what is going on. The blue glow is supposed to be beneath the camera button, but on top of the notch in the frame below. As you can see this shows the correct stacking order in IB:

[image]

However when I build and run this both in the simulator and on the device, it looks like the notch has been stacked above the blue glow. I've tried rearranging the layers in all sorts of ways, but the glow is still clipped no matter what I do. What is wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the constraints. I've had similar problems w/ IB vs. simulator appearance, and the root cause was a constraint conflict.

Specifically, I realized that conflicting constraints resulted when I had copy/pasted a view object to reuse. The constraints of the newly pasted object were not copied properly.

Avoiding the copy/paste resolved the issue (i.e., I dragged a new object into the view and set the new object's settings again).